# No site cert name SSL TLS in browser WIN 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, browser, ssl, tls

I have a problem with certs in my WIN 10 Pro. When I am visiting websites like myetherwallet, steamcommunity etc. I should see their name on green in the address bar, but I can't see it.

> It should say https://www.myetherwallet.com & MYETHERWALLET LLC in
>   your URL bar.

I don't see ***MYETHERWALLET LLC***. It shows up *ONLY* when I use *VPN*. I have a problem to connect some sites like github.com.

After translate this error to ENG:

> It is not possible to securely connect to this site The reason might
>   be that this site is using outdated or unsafe TLS security settings.
>   If this situation repeats, try to contact the owner of this website.

I have contacted github.com and they told me that I should contact my ISP, but I am using the same WiFi on my second PC (Win 10 Home) and there I have not this problem.

Does someone know what may be the problem? I use Bitdefender Total Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by BitDefender's feature called [SSL scanning](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/what-to-do-when-security-certificates-cannot-be-verified-installed-1090.html).

In short, your firewall [intercepts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y69YV.jpg) the HTTPS connection and provides *its own* certificates for every website, in order to scan encrypted traffic.

(This remained mostly unnoticed because installing BitDefender told your browsers to trust its auto-generated certificates, although it's technically very similar to a malicious attack other than that.)

According to BitDefender's website, this "feature" [can be disabled:](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/what-to-do-when-security-certificates-cannot-be-verified-installed-1090.html)

> 1. bring up the main Bitdefender interface
> 2. click on Settings from the upper right toolbar
> 3. From Settings Overview choose Privacy Control
> 4. In the Antiphishing tab use the switch to temporarily turn off Scan SSL feature

Comment: Thanks You. It helped. Now I can use github.com and have **MYETHERWALLET LLC** without VPN in all web browsers except Microsoft Edge. In Edge github.com works, but **MYETHERWALLET LLC** is missing.